# How to handle a keystroke event in java, but pass it on so that it has it's "natural" effect?

Tags: java, jtextarea, keystroke

I have this code that makes some action execute when user is in textArea (JTextArea instance) and 'enter' is pressed:

```
textArea.getInputMap().put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), actionMapKey);
    textArea.getActionMap().put(actionMapKey, new AbstractAction() {

        int numLines, lineStart, lineEnd;
        Element lineElem;
        String lineText;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                         //all the things to be done when enter is pressed
                    }
    });
```

It works fine, but after the action is handled, no newline appears in the textArea.
Is there any way to pass the 'enter' keystroke on so that it actually creates newline?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this the default behaviour of the `JTextArea`, why you need to reinvent the wheel for this. But if you may elaborate a bit, as to what sort of a work you performing in this `actionPerformed(...)` that might be of more help to give a detailed explanation. Though it would be much wise, if you use some `MASK Key like Control or Alt`, in conjunction with `ENTER`, so that the basic functionality of the Component remains as is, as shown in this [example](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/downloads/JTextAreaExample.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to call the super method you are overloading after all of your custom actions.